# Dart Function syntax

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to Dart and Flutter. 
I have come across a programming syntax while looking at `responsive_builder.dart` class as follows:

```
final Widget Function(BuildContext buildContext, SizingInformation sizingInformation) builder;
```

I searched about a lot regarding Function() syntax but somehow did not find anything. Similarly, I tried on https://dartpad.dev as below:

```
class Dog{
   String Function(String j, String u) functionName;
}
```

And dart pad did not complain about it.
Please help me understand what is Function() type syntax.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Define a variable that contains a function and define the type of this variable or actually define a function to be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    class Dog{
   String Function(String j, String u) functionName;
}
```

In this case there's nothing wrong with this syntax. You're only *declaring* a variable `functionName` of type Function that returns a String and takes two arguments `String j, String u` without properly initializing it.

You could do something like:

```
void main() async {

  Dog newDog = Dog(functionName: (String j, String u) => j + ' ' + u );

  print(newDog.functionName('Hello', 'World'));

}

 class Dog{
   final String Function(String j, String u) functionName;
   Dog({this.functionName});
}
```

output:

```
Hello World
```

What I essentially did here was to define the `functionName` Function on the `Dog` class and then pass a *Anonymous Function* of the same type to its *Constructor* when initializing a new `Dog` object called `newDog`.

I can then call `newDog.functionName(String arg1, String arg2)`. This will return a run the *Anonymous Function* we passed earlier to the `newDog` object *Constructor* and return a new concatenated string.

Comment: hello pedro, you want to say that Function type in dart is like delegates in C#? It works like a function pointer?

Comment: I don't know anything about C or C#, but ill try to clarify.1- In Dart Functions are first-class objects and can be passed around or stored into variables. 2- Dart is a strong typed language, and you can declare a _Variable_, it's _name_ and it's _Type_ without initializing it (giving it a value). And that's is essentially what you're doing when you write `String Function(String j, String u) myFunction;`. Later you can assign a value to this variable `myFunction` as you normally would as long you respect its type. In this case it'll be expecting a `String Function(String, String)`.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe this is what you are asking take your example modified slightly function for example

```
String Function(BuildContext context, int index) functionName;
```

Function is just letting dart know that you are declaring a function you can also declare a function like this.

```
String functionName(BuildContext context, int index) {}
```

String in this  example is the return type of the function while BuildContext and int are input types for the function finally context and index are the variable names to be used inside functionName.

For a more detailed explanation here is [Dart Programming Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_functions.htm) you might have already read this though